# Angular quiz app on clicking the respective question number it should emit the question

Tags: angular

I am building a quiz app using Angular. I have displayed questions one after the other. On the right side  I have displayed question numbers. How do I get to display only the respective question when I click on the question number .

Component 1: One question displayed at a time and then with a next button it goes to next question

```
  <div *ngFor="let question of filteredQuestions">  
    <div> Question {{pager.index+1}} of{{pager.count}}</div>

    <h4> Question {{question.id}}</h4>
    <p> {{question.questionText}}</p>

    <mat-radio-group class="radio-group" name="option1" ngModel 
    #option1="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="option"> 
      <mat-radio-button class="radio-button" *ngFor="let option of 
      question.questionOptions" value={{option.optionText}} >
        {{option.optionText}}
      </mat-radio-button>
    </mat-radio-group>

   </div>
```

Component 2
I have the question numbers displayed. I want on clicking each question
number the corresponding question to show

Comment: What you have tried so far? if you post the code that will be helpful

Comment: What this meant `[(ngModel)]="option"` ? doesnt make much sense with this: `*ngFor="let option of question.questionOptions"`, maybe try change it to `[(ngModel)]="selectedOption"`...